# I would like some help getting criteria of gtk programming. What could I do about this?

Tags: c, gtk

Could anyone help me? I have programming skills in C and I'm trying to program gui's using gtk. I wish, from firing an action (a callback function) from a widget (eg a button), I can change any condition or characteristic belonging to any other widget. Ie something like allow full visibility from within the callback function as if all variables in all gui widgets (say a single main application window) were global. How can I address the closest way to accomplish this? So far, the steps I tried to discover underlying concepts in programming with gtk were frustrating me, when I try to make something more complex than simple Hello World tutorial.I also tried using:

```
/* out of main */
struct data_widgets
{
struct data_widgets * myp;
gchar  **loc ;      // LOCAL name
gchar  **rem ;      // REMOTE name
gchar  **pmte ;     // Plain message to encrypt filename
gchar  **lem ;      // Local encrypted message filename 
gchar  **emr ;      // Encrypted message received filename 
gchar  **pmr ;      // Plain message received filename 
gchar  **lopk ;     // Local owner public key filename 
gchar  **crpk ;     // Current remote public key filename  
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
gchar loc_str[100] = "*";       /* LOCAL name for filechoose filter */
gchar rem_str[100] = "*";       /* REMOTE name idem */
gchar pmte_str[100]= "plainmsgtoencrypt"; /* Plain message to encrypt filename  */
gchar lem_str[100] = "localencmsg"; /* Local encrypted message filename  */
gchar emr_str[100] = "encmsgreceiv"; /* Encrypted message received filename */
gchar pmr_str[100] = "plainreceiv"; /* Plain message received filename */
gchar lopk_str[100]= "locownpubkey"; /* Local owner public key filename */
gchar crpk_str[100]= "remotpubkey"; /* Current remote public key filename */

struct data_widgets mydata;

mydata.loc = &loc_str;
mydata.rem = &rem_str;
mydata.pmte = &pmte_str;
mydata.lem = &lem_str;
mydata.emr = &emr_str;
mydata.pmr = &pmr_str;
mydata.lopk = &lopk_str;
mydata.crpk = &crpk_str;
mydata.myp = &mydata;
/* in main */
....
/* in my callback */
struct data_widgets *pp = (struct data_widgets *) data;

/*passing gpointer data as &mydata.myp, and doing (*pp)->(any pointer) this try fail*/
```

Comment: I would like then rephrase my request for help, not so much in the sense of request literature but to perform the programming attempt to which I refer in middle of paragraph, expound on modifying parameters widget broad visibility within the callback function. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how clear it is, but it's more on-topic now. I'll retract my close vote. Thank you for editing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to access widgets from within the callback without having to carry around a bunch of globals. You have some option.

You can pack data and widgets inside a single struct and pass it as `user_data` to the callback.

```
struct snapshot {
    struct data_widgets data;
    GtkWidget *entry;
    GtkWidget *box;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *whatever;
};
/* Now fill and use the above struct as user_data */
```

The `GtkWidget` fields should be initialized in the code you use to create the UI stuff.

You can also set a name for each relevant widget with [gtk_widget_set_name()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-name) ([Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) automatically sets a name on every element). Once you need a widget, just get it with [gtk_widget_get_name()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-name).

```
static void a_callback(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data)
    GtkWidget *an_entry = NULL;
    GtkWidget *toplevel = gtk_widget_get_toplevel(widget);
    if (gtk_widget_is_toplevel(toplevel))
        an_entry = gtk_widget_get_name(toplevel, "name of the entry");
    g_return_if_fail(an_entry != NULL);
    /* ... do something with an_entry ... */
}
```

You can also traverse the widget hierarchy as if it was a DOM or directly bind your data to the widgets with [g_object_set_data()](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set-data) or any valid mixture of the above.

#### Addendum

With `g_object_set_data()` you can attach arbitrary data to any `GObject` instance, e.g.:

```
gchar *text;

/* Bind some data to widget */
g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "pmte", "plainmsgtoencrypt");
g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "lem", "localencmsg");

text = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "pmte");
g_print("%s\n", text); /* Print "plainmsgtoencrypt" */
g_free(text);

text = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "lme");
g_print("%s\n", text); /* Print "localencmsg" */
g_free(text);
```

#### Code cleanup

Your code is messy in many ways: I suggest you forget what you learnt for C and restart from zero. Your data has one level of indirection more than what it is needed, `myp` is bogus, you are specifying size of arrays and initializing it.

Answering your comment: the following code is self-contained and does not throw the error you see.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

struct data_widgets {
    gchar **crpk;
};

void callback(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data) {
    struct data_widgets *data = user_data;
    g_print("%s\n", data->crpk); /* Prints remotpubkey */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gchar crpk_str[100] = "remotpubkey";
    struct data_widgets mydata;

    mydata.crpk = &crpk_str;

    callback(NULL, &mydata);
    return 0;
}
```

The same code, cleaned up in a sane way:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
    gchar *crpk;
} data_t;

void callback(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer user_data) {
    data_t *data = user_data;
    g_print("%s\n", data->crpk); /* Prints remotpubkey */
}

int main() {
    data_t mydata;

    mydata.crpk = "remotpubkey";

    callback(NULL, &mydata);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: myp is a pointer to the struct, inner the struct passed. The main concep is do not generate global variables in a manner to reach portability of code. I will try to apply his advice trying to advance what I try. After testing I will make known the result. Of course, thank you very much for your valuable contribution. Regarding your last paragraph (g_objet_set_data), I do not know how to use it and tutorials that I can find on the web do not include degrees of complexity like this.

Comment: I still do not grasp it: having access to `myp` means you already have the pointer to the same struct. Two cases: or you have some serious problem with C or I totally fail to understand your code.

Comment: I added anyway an example of use of g_object_{get,set}_data.

Comment: In my code I pass (gpointer data)-a pointer to void-, as &mydata.myp, which is a pointer initialized with the address of my data_widgets structure. In my callback I make a cast data_widgets struct * pp = (struct data_widgets *) data, which should allow me without problems, to make a reference (*pp)->(any_struct_member) into the function. The data_struct structure is declared outside of main, so its arithmetic of pointer should be visible inside the function too. But I get an error: eccelgam-jvr05.c.20:30: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type.

Comment: If you directly pass `&mydata` you will get the exact same result, without needing to incomodate additional fields and code.

Comment: Initially I had already tried what you aim it, but the compiler does not like the use of reference (pointer)->(member), so it throws the same error. I think it is because Glib (and other layers) limit the action of the programmer, changing this transparent visibility for a opaque type.
About what I know, the C programming is up to the programmer responsibility checking consistency of code, without limitation of use.

Comment: Passing `&mydata` works, believe me. You get the above error when you try to use `GtkWidget` (or any other struct still not defined, such as your `struct data_widgets`) instead of `GtkWidget *`. I did not suggest to use `struct data_widgets myp`, I suggested to get rid of it.

Comment: I believe you, even more, I tried it and does not accuse error, but does not do what I want. If I make something like g_print("%s", (gchar*) pp); does not accuse error, but this prints gibberish.
When I try to do what I want, ie g_print ("%s", (gchar*) (* pp)->crpk); this throws the error I mentioned.

Comment: Of course it prints gibberish: you are trying to print a struct of pointers and this does not make sense. You shoud use `g_print("%s", pp->crpk)` or whatever field you want to print. This is basic C pointer handling though.

Comment: Pardon, in your case you should use `g_print("%s", *pp->crpk)` because you have a double indirection in your fields.

Comment: This is just what I did, and gave the error I mention.

Comment: You did call `g_print ("%s", (gchar*) (* pp)->crpk)`, and this is really different from `g_print("%s", *pp->crpk)`: `->` takes precedence over `*`.

Comment: I wrote it so, to ensure that take precedence, but I think unnecessary parentheses. However, I tried both, and also putting *(pp->crpk), and always throws the same error. I have the feeling that the compiler rejects any attempt to use a reference (pointer)->(member). If you have some time, I invite you to try it for yourself.

Comment: I added the section _Code cleanup_ in the answer: no errors there. Sorry but your questions are too vague and bring too much guesswork on my side. IMO your original code has too much problems to be addressed with a single question.

Comment: Anyway, I am very grateful for your response and time spent, and I apologize for my lack of clarity in what I say.

Comment: I give an astounding result about the work presented. First, the code submitted works properly without mistakes I've stated. I made an elementary error not evident. Ideas and concepts on how they should operate were proven to be correct. Even using internal pointer to structure containing the address of same, and passing it to the callback. The fool mistake I'd made, and I discovered quite by accident: (outside main) I declared/implemented my callback before declaring my struct. On one hand I feel like a fool, but otherwise I am happy to see that ideas were properly implemented. thanks.